# Recursively scp except current directory

Tags: unix, scp

Is there a way to `scp` all files in a directory recursively to a remote machine and keep their original filenames but don't copy the directory it is in?

```
dir1/file
dir1/dir2/file2
```

so the contents of `dir1` would be copied only. `dir1` would not be created. The `dir2` directory would be created with `file2` inside though.

I have tried `scp -r dir1 remote:/newfolder` but it creates `dir1` in the `/newfolder` directory on `remote`. I don't want it to create that `dir1` directory. Just put all the files inside of `dir1` into `newfolder`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
cd dir1
scp -r . remote:/newfolder
```

This avoids giving `scp` a chance to do anything with the name `dir1` on the remote machine.  You might also prefer:

```
(cd dir1; scp -r . remote:/newfolder)
```

This leaves your shell in its original directory, while working the same (because it launches a sub-shell that does the `cd` and `scp` operations).

Answer (score 9):

This means copy the list of files made by the shell expansion dir1/* to the remote location remote:/newfolder

```
scp -r dir1/* remote:/newfolder
```

Comment: I like this answer because it avoids having to do a `cd`.  If your next statement after `scp` expects you to be in your original dir, then you'd have to do yet another step to `cd` back to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dot syntax with relative path.

```
scp -r dir1/. remote:/newfolder
```

If the remote directory does not exist it is created.